# How to convert Alphanumeric in EditText to Number Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, numbers

How do I change the alphabet and numeric in EditText to Number?

**Example :**

```
EditText = ABC123

result =  123123
```

or

```
EditText = AA5BB6CC7

result =  115226337
```

Comment: Please post what you've tried

Comment: What would happen with J-Z?

Answer (score 0):

In order to support what you want, you would have to either create a mapping of letters to their numerical value or perform the conversion based on the ascii value.

Your logic might look something like this:

```
private EditText editText;

String text = editText.getText().toString();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < text.length()l; i++) {
    char s = text.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isLetter(s)) {
       //Perform your logic here
       //Get value from hashmap
       char converted = letterToNummber.get(s);
       //Or perform conversion
       char convertedOther = s - 65;
       sb.append(converted/convertedOther);
    } else {
      //Character is a number, no conversion needed
     sb.append(s);
    }
}
sb.toString();
```

You didn't specify if you work only with capital letters so I assumed you do.

Comment: What would happen with J-Z?

Comment: @g00se - The OP didn't specify the logic and as I stated, I was going on an assumption.

Comment: Yes. I asked him the same but thought I'd ask you too ;)

Comment: Maybe `s = s.codePoints().map(cp -> cp >= 'A' && cp <= 'I'? cp - 0x10 : cp).mapToObj(Character::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());`